# Selenium getText() changes order of li items at times

Tags: java, selenium

I have some code with list items. If I try to do a getText() using selenium webdriver, at times the order of the li tags gets changed.

```
<div class="alphabets"><h4>Prerequisites:</h4>
<ul>
<li><a name="abc" class="abc">abc</a>,</li>
<li><a name="xyz" class="xyz">xyz</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

driver.findElement(By.className("alphabets")).getText()
gives me 
Prerequisites: xyz, abc

I have not been able to figure out the reason why this happens. Any inputs would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findAllElements` method which will give you the webelement of particular path.

In your case you can do this:

```
List<WebElement> listTags = driver.findElements(your-path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alphabets']"));
List<WebElement> alphabets = list.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(int i=0;i<alphabets.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(alphabets.get(i).getText());
}
```

Hope this helps.